# c# call asp.net application from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a console application and when something happens in that console, I wanna call a asp.net page, which is in a asp.net project in my visual studio 2013, any help please

I tried this

```
 HttpClient d = new HttpClient();
```

but it seems that the HttpClient is not existed

Comment: @Aria the console application is using sql dependency to keep watching for changes in DB, and when a changes happen, I wanna open a asp.net page. What do you think? should that sql dependency be in a console application or not?

Comment: Read: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `System.Net.Http` [NuGet Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/2.0.20710), that contains the `HttpClient` class.

To download the package in your project, click on the **Tools** menu, then **NuGet Package Manager** and then **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**
In the dialog just search for **System.Net.Http** and then click the **Install** button.

Comment: and then? how can I tell the `client` instance to run? I did this: `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");`

Comment: You can call it's methods like `client.GetAsync(url);` to perform requests.

Comment: Here you can read the basics of `HttpClient`: http://www.jayway.com/2012/03/13/httpclient-makes-get-and-post-very-simple/

Comment: still that `GetAsync` doesn't open any page. why please?

Comment: Does it throw some kind of exception, or what exactly happens?

Comment: now it is working, i have chosen another way, thanks